# Can the sup metric and the uniform metric be considered the same? (topology munkres)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

[image]

I'm studying thm 50.5 (the imbedding thm)

Why did Munkres write the sup metric $\rho$ instead of the uniform metric $\bar{\rho}$ ??

$$
\bar{\rho}(f,g) 
= \sup \bigl\{ \min \{ \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert, 1 \} 
\mathrel{:} x \in X \bigr\}
$$

According to Thm 43.5, isn't it right to use the uniform metric $\bar{\rho}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $X$ is compact in 50.5, all continuous functions are bounded and so there is no need for a truncation of $d$, and he can use $\rho$ right away. And $\rho$ is also a complete metric on the function space.

In 43.5 he needs $\bar{\rho}$ because there the metric is a general one and $\rho$ need not be defined.